# spring security: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor] found

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to add spring-security to my rest app.
I followed the tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) on spring website to do it but there it uses spring-boot component which I don't want to use, maybe problem is here.

My security configuration is here:

```
@Configuration
@Order(2147483636)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}

private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                    .getName());
            if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                String token = csrf.getToken();
                if (cookie == null || token != null
                        && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                    cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
ERROR ContextLoader:353 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:678)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:243)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:200)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1838)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 54 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:616)
... 56 more
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation on your SecurityConfiguration class.

This would have been added by Spring-boot automatically, however since you opted for not using Spring-boot **this needs to be taken care of manually**.

Comment: Reads: Do not use this framework without it's meta-framework! :D

Answer (score 14):

I use Spring Boot and trigger the same or similar issue with a custom subclass of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. I needed to add `@EnableWebSecurity` to main class to work around the `No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor<?>]` exception.

Comment: I ran into this error in a Spring Boot application when I set the config property `spring.main.web-application-type: none` to value `none`. Adding `@EnableWebSecurity` to my `Application` class resolved it for that case, too.

Answer (score 7):

You need add **@EnableWebSecurity** and **@Configuration** , the code below is from **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** class, see exception message :

```
private ObjectPostProcessor<Object> objectPostProcessor = new ObjectPostProcessor<Object>() {
    public <T> T postProcess(T object) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                ObjectPostProcessor.class.getName()
                        + " is a required bean. Ensure you have used @EnableWebSecurity and @Configuration");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

The error message doesn't tell you what the root cause is. I spent hours trying different answers. Eventually, I fixed the problem when I found the right place to put the break point and find the exact exception with the exact class that threw the exception.

Place a break point in buildMessage of the class: org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter. There you can go up the stack to find the exact class that is causing the exception.

Answer (score 5):

In my case a Spring Security configuration was accidently included in my applicationContext.
So **my** solution was to **exclude** the Spring Security configuration.

**Note**

This is not an answer to the question but a solution for the error message in the title.
So please consider other users who search for this error and find this post, before voting me down.

Answer (score 3):

check your `<context:component-scan>`to make sure you have your package covered.