# Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to create OAuth2 Server Provider using this tutorial [Spring OAuth2](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v) . The main difference between example and my project - I do not use Spring Boot. I try to split this classes ([GitHub example link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/java/demo/AuthserverApplication.java)) I created 2 classes:

```
@Configuration
@Order(-20)
@EnableResourceServer
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
  }
```

}

Second class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
            new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "foobar".toCharArray())
            .getKeyPair("test");
    converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
    return converter;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("acme")
            .secret("acmesecret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token",
                    "password").scopes("openid").autoApprove(true).accessTokenValiditySeconds(30);
}

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).accessTokenConverter(
            jwtAccessTokenConverter());
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess(
            "isAuthenticated()");
  }

}
```

But when I try to start this code, I get:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2AuthorizationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private   org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.example.configuration.security.OAuth2AuthorizationConfiguration.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5066)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.example.configuration.security.OAuth2AuthorizationConfiguration.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 60 more
```

I guess, the problem is in Spring Boot that I do not use in my app. 
I tried following solutions: [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633555/how-to-inject-authenticationmanager-using-java-configuration-in-a-custom-filter), [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081578/spring-security-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-org)
I use only code-based configuration. 
Additional info:
Java 8
spring-security-oauth2 - 2.0.7.RELEASE, 
spring-security-version - 4.0.1.RELEASE, 
spring-version - 4.0.6.RELEASE.

How to fix it?

**UPDATE**

I created

```
@Configuration
public class AuthManager extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }

}
```

And now I have exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager org.com.example.configuration.security.WebSecurityConfig.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 100 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationManager': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
```

This exception in OAuth2AuthorizationConfiguration class.

Comment: This discussion may help - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11136

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Create another `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class that will be the "main" configuration and add the following code in order to expose an `AuthenticationManager` bean:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
  return authenticationManager();
}
```

Comment: I have added this because I have the same error in my test environment. This resolved my test environment but I can't login I have 401 error.

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Just remove `protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method. According to javadoc I don't need this method.

Answer (score 1):

After you add the bean You should remove @Autowired from authenticationManager

```
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
      return authenticationManager();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

IN the same class where you are extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter , add below piece of code

```
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```