# A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am writing applications in spring boot and after adding spring boot security , I ran into a compilation problem. Can someone help me or has anyone had such a problem before?

Problem:

```
Description:

A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' in your configuration.
```

Code

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserService userService;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081578/spring-security-nosuchbeandefinitionexception-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-org

Comment: Yes ! Thanks for your help !
so that others could see my solution I added ``` @EnableWebSecurity ``` above the class