# Error when using @EnableWebFluxSecurity in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to setup a simple spring boot application. It can be started if I don't use `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` annotatoin.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    open class ArticleWebSecurityConfig {

        @Bean
        open fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain = http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .build()
    }
```

The following error occurrs when I start it:

> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' defined in
> class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'defaultSecurityFilterChain' parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

> #### Description
>
> Parameter 0 of method defaultSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I used the following `@Bean` but stil get the same errror.

```
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    @Bean
    open fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
    }
```

These are my dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: the "configure" bean expects an autowired HttpSecurity bean as its parameter. you need to define an HttpSecurity bean, you can do it in the same class.

Comment: @TomElias Could you please answer this question? I did not  get what you really mean.

Comment: can you please provide a small reproducible example

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.Some of your dependencies are bringing **spring-boot-starter-web**. You need to find who using mvn dependency:tree and exclude it in your pom.xml.

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
```

And also add as seperate dependecy the

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also another addition you should make is add : spring.main.web-application-type=reactive in application properties

Answer (score 0):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Adding above dependency solved it for me. Using Spring 6, Boot 3, Java 17.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add both `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` and `@Configuration` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58555230/2896809).

Comment: No, it does not work. I just updatd my question.